# c1.list_budget[choose_cat].append(a2) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

When I try to run this below code then following error occur and I am new at Python programming. Please tell me the solution.

Thanks

```
c1 = Category()
c1.cat_print()
choose_cat = int(input("Choose category Between 0 To 4: "))
a1 = c1.list_category[choose_cat]
amount = int(input("Enter Amount: "))
a2 = c1.list_budget[choose_cat] + amount
c1.list_budget[choose_cat].append(a2)
print(a1, a2)
note = input("Enter Note: ")
print(amount, choose_cat, note)
```

Comment: `c1.list_budget[choose_cat]` is an integer.  You cannot append to an integer.

Comment: Did you mean to append to `c1.list_budget`?

Comment: yes, I want to update budget so I try to append `list_budget`.

Comment: Well, if `c1.list_budget` is the thing that you want to `append` to, then `c1.list_budget` is what should come before `.append`. I don't understand why there should be any confusion. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Ok but I want add budget in particular category that category enter by user. @KarlKnechtel